# re-exporting object with material gets more memory

Tags: objects

I got Many FBX and now I'm importing to paint them. Then I export them like the same file.

Example With one of FBX. FBX get example 550KB, I paint it, now it's  get's
for example 1MB

Any body know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you export a previously blank (without material) obj, obviously it takes more memory, because you added material to it.
I don't know if this helps you... Maybe I misunderstood the question.